# Cant open a .sh file in ChromeOS?

Tags: linux, bash, google-chrome-os

So I’ve been struggling while learning how2linux, and I’m trying to install screenfetch.

I have a `.sh` file in my downloads, I’ve gotten to this point:

- Found the file in the terminal.
- Made it executable.
- Tried to execute it.

Other notable information, it’s in developer mode, I’ve gone from read only to read/write on all partitions and I have permissions to do any command.

But it says I cannot open it? Terminal screenshot below. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: @CalebXu I get the same end result, a green file name, still cant open it.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the slash from your command. `sh /screenfetch.sh` searches for `screenfetch.sh` under root directory, not downloads. Just execute `sh ~/Downloads/screenfetch.sh`